# Case When for Specific Criteria

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that lists employees ratings throughout the years, but the years are all listed in one column. I am trying to get the meeting years to have their own columns with the score, and if they do not have a score for it to be null.

THe Code so far:

```
SELECT Employee_ID, Meeting_Year, Manager_Readiness_Rating
FROM  dbo.v_sc17_TMS_Data_Career_Meeting_Rating
GROUP BY Employee_ID, Meeting_Year, Manager_Readiness_Rating
```

So if the meeting_year is 2012 I want all 2012 Manager_Readiness_Rating listed in the column for the employees. Here is some examples

```
ID    Year      Rating
1     2011  11 
2     2012  10 
3     2010  09
4     2010  03  
4     2011  03
```

I would like it to look like

```
ID  2010   2011  2012
1    NULL   11    NULL
2    NULL   NULL  1
3    09    NULL    NULL
4    03    03    NULL
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data and your expected output based on that data?

Comment: You're trying to pivot the data. That is merely a data presentation issue that you should solve in your front end. Having said that, if you want to pivot data that way you will need to add each column manually for each of the months. You can not just generate any amount of columns dynamically, you have to know them in advance

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Employee_ID, Meeting_Year, GROUP_CONCAT(Manager_Readiness_Rating)
FROM dbo.v_sc17_TMS_Data_Career_Meeting_Rating
GROUP BY Employee_ID, Meeting_Year
```

Comment: This does not work in SQL, and it is not what I am looking for. I posted what I need it to look like. Thank you though

Answer (score 0):

This is flagged as MySQL, but the `dbo` makes me think it's SQL Server. This query should work for either one:

```
SELECT
  Employee_ID AS ID,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Year = 2010 THEN Rating END) AS R2010,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Year = 2011 THEN Rating END) AS R2011,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Year = 2012 THEN Rating END) AS R2012
FROM dbo.v_sc17_TMS_Data_Career_Meeting_Rating
GROUP BY Employee_ID
ORDER BY 1
```